# Scraping table from webpage made of <div> tags

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to scrape the table from the following [link](https://mahabocw.in/safety-kit-benefits-distribution/).

I have written a script using selenium that could click through next pages, but the table in each page seems to be having no `table` tag. Instead it seems to contain only `div` tags. I find it difficult to scrape table through this site. Any help would be really apreciated.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://mahabocw.in/safety-kit-benefits-distribution/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

next_button = '/html/body/div/div[6]/div/article/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]/div[3]/button'
click_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button)
click_next.click()
```

**Edit 1**

I have just now observed that when I click a row, I am able to download all previous rows along with it as csv.
[image: exporting as csv]

However the problem is that the `go to last page` button doesn't work here. So I have to click through the next page button. I used my selenium script through to click through to consecutive pages, but it doesn't work after going through about 50 pages or so. I want to click through to the final page and then export it as csv.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://mahabocw.in/safety-kit-benefits-distribution/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

for i in range(1000000):
    next_button = '/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/article/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]/div[3]/button'
    click_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button)
    click_next.click()
```

This is the complete code I am using to try to get to the last page. Also I have no clue of the total number of pages in the website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some websites are purposefully engineered this way to discourage scraping.

Comment: Ohh that's sad. How can I scrape through content now. Is there anyway possible to scrape tables from such a website?

Comment: @metatoaster I am able to export as csv, but for that I need to get to the last page now by clicking the next button. Do you know of anyway I can accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

As for '>' button you can use shorter xpath:

```
//button[text() = 'Next']
```

As for table data, well I will write it in C#-like code:

```
var result = new List<List<string>>();
var rows = WebDriver.FindElements("//div[@role = 'row' and @row-index and div]");
foreach (var row in rows)
{
   var rowData = new List<string>();
   var cells = row.FindElements("/div");

   foreach (var cell in cells) rowData.Add(cell.Text);
   result.Add(rowData);
}
```

Comment: But I am using python.

Comment: I don't know Python, but I am pretty sure you can translate this example. To solve your problem you should: 
1) find all rows with xpath "//div[@role = 'row' and @row-index and div]"
2) foreach (or from first till last) row find cells by "/div" xpath;
2.1) foreach cell get text and put it to *cell-values* list/array;
2.2) put *cell-values* array/list to the *table-values* matrix (list of list).